# Pandas: update a column based on index in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to update couple of columns in a dataframe using a multiplying factor in another df (both the dfs have a 'KEY' column). Though I was able to achieve this, it takes a lot of processing time since I have a few million records. Looking for a more optimum solution if any.

Let me explain my scenario using dummy dfs. I have a dataframe df1 as below

```
In [8]: df1
Out[8]: 
   KEY  col2  col3  col4
0    1     1    10     5
1    2     7    13     8
2    1    12    15    12
3    4     3    23     1
4    3    14     5     6
```

Now I want to change `col2` and `col3` by a *factor* that I fetch from the below `df2` dataframe based on the `KEY`.

```
In [11]: df2
Out[11]: 
     FACTOR
KEY        
1       100
2      3000
3      1000
4       200
5        50
```

I'm using the below for loop to achieve what I need.

```
In [12]: for index, row in df2.iterrows():
             df1.loc[(df1['KEY']==index), ['col2', 'col3']] *= df2.loc[index]['FACTOR']

In [13]: df1
Out[13]: 
   KEY   col2   col3  col4
0    1    100   1000     5
1    2  21000  39000     8
2    1   1200   1500    12
3    4    600   4600     1
4    3  14000   5000     6
```

This does the job. But my actual data has a few million records that come in real time and takes about 15 seconds to complete for each batch of incoming data. I am looking for a better solution since the for loop seems to be doing it in `O(n)` complexity

Answer (score 0):

you should use a merge:

```
c=df1.merge(df2,on="KEY")
```

the c dataframe will now contain the "FACTOR" column which is the result you want to achieve

if one of the fields to merge is the index, you can use :

```
c=df1.merge(df2,left_on="KEY",right_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. But what I wanted is not just merge the “Factor” but get that to multiply the columns in df1 based on the key. However, this gave me the idea that I could accomplish what I want to in two steps. Merge first and then use the `multiply` function on my two columns to get the final output.

Comment: And I'm giving a +1 coz it gave me a better idea to deal with my problem, although now it would involve two steps unlike a single line that I wanted. Thanks @WNG